# Error when using sqlite3 with python

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

```
import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur=conn.cursor()

cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS students")
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE students(name text, age text)''')
cur.execute("INSERT INTO students VALUES ('john','22')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO students VALUES ('kris','33')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO students VALUES ('mathew','25')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO students VALUES ('sarah','40')")

conn.commit()

ageofstudent = '25'

cur.execute("SELECT name FROM students WHERE age =?",ageofstudent)

print [str(record[0]) for record in cur.fetchall()]

conn.close()
```

Hello friends.. I am using this simple example to get some help from you. I dont understand why I am getting error on executing this simple code. I am new to sqlite3 database. The error is shown below

```
> >>> 
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/labuser/Google
> Drive/Smart Lab Projects/wireshark lte signalling
> parser/foroverstock.py", line 18, in <module>
>     cur.execute("SELECT name FROM students WHERE age =?",ageofstudent) ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current
> statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
> >>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)'s `cursor.execute` takes an `iterable` for its parameters.  You need to call it like:

```
cur.execute("SELECT name FROM students WHERE age =?", (ageofstudent,))
```

Because its expecting an iterable, it's treating the '2' and '5' of '25' as separate parameters.